# pass parameters/data in hyperlink - laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-controller, laravel-route

I am trying to pass data from one page to another via hyperlink. Here is url.

```
<a href="{{url('page-name/sometext')}}">click here </a>
```

My Route:-

```
Route::get('page-name/{sometext}', 'MyController@pagename');
```

In Controller:-

```
function pagename(Request $request){
        $sometext=$request->sometext;
        return view('page-name')-with($sometext);
}
```

Now trying to get data in second page.

```
{{$sometext}}
```

But it showing that error:-

***Object of class Illuminate\View\View could not be converted to int***

Kindly suggest, if there is another way for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using get method and get with parameter. so there is no need to write `Request $request`

**HTML**

```
<a href="{{url('page-name/sometext')}}">click here </a>
```

**Route**:-

```
Route::get('page-name/{sometext}', 'MyController@pagename');
```

**Controller**:- needs to change

```
function pagename($sometext){
        return view('page-name',compact('sometext'));
}
```

Now **page-name.blade.php** file you can get this variable as

```
{{ $sometext }}
```

Comment: it works but now the page url has changed from http://127.0.0.1:8000/page-name to http://127.0.0.1:8000/page-name/sometext, 
so this page not connecting with other [css/js/bootstrap] files cz these were connected with the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/page-name
.how to overcome this one?

Comment: I think that issue is of loading css js. You can `ctrl+U` and check the url.

Comment: i set css, js url according to 127.0.0.1:8000/page-name bcz there will be multiple text variables will be sent to the page, and the page url will contineously change
like 127.0.0.1:8000/page-name/text-one, 127.0.0.1:8000/page-name/text-two etc, then how to set css, js, bootstrap links for that page.

Comment: @SajjadAli have you tried linking your css, js, or anything within your public folder using `{{ asset('css/style.css') }}`. This way you won't have to manually change your linking as it will always point to your public folder. UNLESS you linked it directly from a website (e.g bootstrap's cdn, jquery library online, etc)

Comment: tried, but was not sure why to use asset, thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you pass data in route with get method like this,

```
Route::get('page-name/{sometext}', 'MyController@pagename');
```

then you need to define number of parameter in your method as,

```
function pagename(Request $request,$someText=""){
        //$sometext=$request->sometext;
        return view('page-name')-with("someText",$someText);
}
```