# Laravel how to properly pass data to href

Tags: php, laravel

sorry if the question is kind of newbie. I am new to php and laravel, still trying to learn through tutorial.

I am trying to pass the 'No' in my database to the url, so that the url when I clicked on Daftar, it will show

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/{No}](http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/%7BNo%7D)

[Webpage designed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlwaS.png)

I did try to put it this way in my href tag but did not manage to get the result I want

here is my code

**search.blade.php**

```
            @if(isset($namelist))

            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thread>
                    <tr>
                        <th>No</th>
                        <th>Nama</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Tindakan</th>
                    </tr>
                </thread>
                <tbody>
                    @if(count($namelist) > 0)
                        @foreach($namelist as $nama)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $nama->No }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $nama->Name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $nama->ID }}</td>
                                <td>
                                <a href="search/".$nama[No]>DAFTAR</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    @else

                        <tr><td>Tiada rekod ditemui, sila daftar secara manual di kaunter pendaftaran</td></tr>
                    @endif
                </tbody>
            </table>

            @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**searchController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class searchController extends Controller
{
    function search(request $request){

        if(isset($_GET['query'])){
            
            $search_text = $_GET['query'];
            $namelist = DB::table('namelist')-> where ('ID','LIKE','%'.$search_text.'%')->paginate(100);
            return view('search',['namelist'=>$namelist]);
        }

        elseif(isset($_GET['query'])){
            $search_text1 = $_GET['query'];
            $namelist = DB::table('namelist')-> where ('No','LIKE','%'.$search_text1.'%')->paginate(100);
            return view('search',['namelist'=>$namelist1]);
        }
    
        else{
            return view('search');
        }
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\searchController;
use App\Http\Controllers\daftar;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

route::get('/search',[searchController::class, 'search'])->name('web.search');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Thank you

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58482838/6309457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple ways to do that. In my opinion, the simplest way would be
 `<a href="search/ {{ $nama->No] }}">DAFTAR</a>`.

Actually, what you have already done. Only with the Bladesyntax. And there is a small mistake in your example. Namely, your double quotes.  `<a href="search/".$nama[No]>DAFTAR</a>` should be:

`<a href="search/<?php echo $nama[No] ?>">DAFTAR</a>` or better `<a href="search/ {{ $nama->No] }}">DAFTAR</a>`.

For the sake of completeness. the most elegant way would be to work with components.

Comment: Thanks for answering, the code work, but do you have any idea why the output url show
http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/%201 when the actual number is 1 and not 201?

Thanks again

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can recall this variable passed in the url to the next page that it will redirect to?

Comment: @AmirShouqqie Here, too, there are several possibilities. You can: 1) pass the varaible as a query parameter, 2) store it in the cookie or localStorage at the client (JS Solution). With the query parameter, you then have access with the Laravel request Object (Request $request).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<td>
    <a href="{{ route('web.search', ['No'=>*given_variable_here*]) }}">DAFTAR</a>
</td>
```

Enter the variable at *given_variable_here* above.

Also, you did not prepare the route to accept the passed variable in your `web.php`. This can be corrected like this:

```
Route::get('/search/{No}',[searchController::class, 'search'])->name('web.search');
```

Lastly, I'm not too sure about capitalizing the 'N' in the `No` you want to use. Should you have problems, start by placing these in lowercase. And if you're using VS Code make sure to add the extensions `Laravel Extra Intellisense`, `Laravel Blade Snippets` and `Laravel Snippets`. They are a great help. Let me know if this helps.